# Reading input not knowing its size in c++

Tags: c++, input, infinite

I have not found good answer for my question so i decided to ask my own question.

I need to read input from console with my own function in following format:

a RL

b RLRL

c RLLL

...

in general:
(character)(space)(character sequence or empty)(new line character)

I want to read it into char arrays one by one. I mean I want to read one line, do something with data, then read second one and so on...

Problem is that I do not know number of lines and I do not know how to stop it.
Checking if it is new line character (ASCII 10) does not work because it is in every single line.

There is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int input_size;
char c;
bool finish;

inline int read(char* v, char* arr) {
    int counter = 0;
    c = getchar();

    *v = c; //Pobranie wartości węzła
    input_size++;

    char* tmp = arr;
    c = getchar();
    c = getchar();
    while (c != 32 && c != 10) {
        input_size++;
        *tmp++ = c;
        c = getchar();
        counter++;
    }
    if(c == 10)
        finish = false;
    return counter;
}

void show(char* t, int c) {
    char* tmp = t;
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        cout << *tmp;
        tmp++;
    }
    delete[] tmp;
}

int main()
{

    finish = true;
    char* a = new char[1];
    char* b = new char[64];

    while(finish) {
        int c = read(a, b);
        cout << "char: " << *a << endl;
        cout << "char sequence: ";
        show(b,c);
        cout << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the example of [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), specifically the for-loop. That gives you all the lines one by one.

Comment: I need to do it with getchar() and my own function. It's in my task instructions. I need to count input characters as well maybe that's why it is required.

Comment: implement your own `getline` using `getchar` then? Stop when you hit a newline character.

Comment: Can you use `std::string` or do you have to reimplement that too?

Comment: @AndyG It would be good, but new line character means both next line and end of data and I do not know how to distinguish it?

Comment: @pjdev: Also check against EOF? Alternatively, since it appears you're allowed to use `cin`, you would implement `getline` via `cin` and check the state of the stream after each character read. All said, this is a ridiculous constraint your professor has placed upon you.